# Oracle hierarchical query record prior to max level record

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following Oracle SQL query:

```
select   id_emp_no,
         LEVEL,
         CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF isleaf
from  my_table  
start with id_emp_no = :x
connect by prior my_mgr = id_emp_no 
ORDER BY level
```

This produces the following output:

```
ID_EMP_NO   LEVEL   ISLEAF
11          1       0
22          2       0
33          3       0
44          4       0
55          5       0   <<====
66          6       1
```

Based on the above output, the actual result ID_EMP_NO that I am specifically after is where ID_EMP_NO = 55, that is the record preceeding the max level and the record prior to ISLEAF equalling 1.

So I only want to return the record where ID_EMP_NO = 55.

Comment: put in an inline view, and then check for isleaf=1?

Comment: assuming you have top-down manager-employee hierarchy, make sure you understand that `connect by prior my_mgr = id_emp_no` actually goes UP the tree. a lot of people confuses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that `prior` is nothing but an operator specifying a value of this column from an upper level of the hierarchy, which means you can use it (almost) anywhere in your query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0ecf/7)

```
select prior id_emp_no 
  from my_table  
 where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 
 start with id_emp_no = 11
connect by prior my_mgr = id_emp_no
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0ecf/7/0)**:

```
| PRIORID_EMP_NO |
------------------
|             55 |
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was after. Thanks.